# Rails Hartl Tutorial: Unable to Fix NoMethodError in PasswordResetsTest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

I am getting the following `NoMethodError` even though my database table has the `reset_sent_at` column and `User.last.reset_sent_at` is not nil. 
I will appreciate if anyone can help in fixing this error. Thanks.

```
PasswordResetsTest#test_password_resets:
NoMethodError: undefined method `reset_sent_at=' for #<User:0x00007f8e34164210>
Did you mean?  reset_token=
    app/models/user.rb:66:in `create_reset_digest'
    app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:14:in `create'
    test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:19:in `block in <class:PasswordResetsTest>'
```

Comment: Please provide your code which raises this error

Comment: Someone helped fix it. I was not doing rake db:test:prepare after rake db:migrate, and hence reset_sent_at was showing in the development.sqlite3 table but not in the test.sqlite3 table.